# Bash check for boolean value in env var

Tags: bash, shell, boolean

I'd often like to gate some functionality based on an environment variable. If that variable is set to some "true like" value, I'd like to take the branch, and if it is *unset* **or** set to a false-like value I'd like to not take it.

Is there anything better than:

```sh
if [[ "$FOO" -eq 1 ]]; then
  ...
fi
```

One problem with the above is `FOO=2` evaluates to false, when I think the reasonable expectation would be true (or some kind of error).

?

Comment: Define "better".

Comment: No, not really, but there is no need to quote `"$FOO"` within `[[ ... ]]`, but it is required within `[ ... ]`. (doesn't hurt anything)

Comment: @BeeOnRope: What is a _false-like_ value?

Comment: @chepner - better could be shorter, more canonical, fewer footguns, compatible with more versions of bash, whatever.

Comment: @user1934428 - it is up to you to define. E.g., if the canonical/best pattern has specific values it supports, then I'm good to go with that.

Comment: @BeeOnRope That's too broad. The answer I would give to maximize portability would be far different from the answer I would give using  `bash` extensions to make it more readable.

Comment: @chepner - I care about protability least. I care most about "reasonable behavior" (e.g., if the variable is not set it should not fail or evaluate to "true"), and then second about terseness.

Comment: I mention portability mostly because is there is some good solution that only works in Bash 4.x, then it's not a good solution for me (but I think this is usually implied for bash questions).

Comment: And that's *exactly* the kind of constraints you should put in the question, rather than just saying "better".

Comment: @chepner - I wanted to leave it a bit open because there is often an obvious answer that is better in most or all respects, and adding constraints tends to make people pedantic, e.g., if I mention portability when someone goes spelunking back in the bash source to find what version works on 0.05 or something. It's not intended to be a trick question. If there is some tough tradeoff among various criteria, then a good answer may evaluate them. A good answer may also just make a reasonable judgement about what matters and based it on that.

Comment: If someone _really_ cares about my exact priorities, well now it is down here in the comments. Feel free to edit it into the question if you think it belongs there.

Comment: `when I think the reasonable expectation would be true (or some kind of error)` I don't understand, why would you expect an error when `FOO=2`?

Comment: @KamilCuk - some people might want to only accept exactly two values, a "true" and a "false" value, and any other value would be considered an error (e.g., the user is passing 2 it probably means they misunderstand the semantics of `FOO` variable). I'm not saying it's the only way: another way would be to accept not set, empty or 0 as "false" and everything else as "true" (no error condition).

Comment: @BeeOnRope : I don't think there is a canonical way to represent true and false on the shell level. In some projects I have seen use the string `T` for true and `F` for false, but then you have to define what an unset variable, a set but empty variable, or a variable having one of the strings `t`, `f`, `true`, `false`, or maybe even `yes` or `no` mean.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For this purpose I like to use flags as arithmetic expressions. That leads to a concise and intuitive syntax, in my opinion.

```
if (( $FLAG )); then
    echo true  # FLAG is defined and FLAG != 0
else
    echo false  # FLAG is undefined or FLAG = 0
fi
```

Answer (score 3):

Try variant with `case`

```
case $FOO in
    1|[yY]|[yY]es|[tT]rue) echo ok  ;;
    0|[nN]|[nN]o|[fF]alse) echo fail;;
    *                    ) echo 'fail by default';;
esac
```

Update after KamilCuk comment

```
case "${FOO:-false}" in
    1|[yY]|[yY]es|[tT]rue) echo ok  ;;
    0|[nN]|[nN]o|[fF]alse) echo fail;;
esac
```

Comment: I would quote `FOO` and because I often code with `set -e`, would add `"${FOO:-false}"`